# How to make specific app run as admin

Tags: windows-10, administrator, uac

I'm running Windows 10 pro, and I have several people using my machine in my business. I am the sole administrator.

All my employees have user accounts, but they are just standard(non admin) users.

I have a particular program that does not like to be ran except by an administrator, but my standard users need to be able to run this without my password.

Is there some way I can do it without runas /savecred or some very insecure approach?

Comment: If you can identify *why* it won't run without admin permissions, you might be able to grant access to a particular file path or registry key without opening Pandora's box.  So ask yourself.. what fails?  Do you get an error?

Comment: Find what the application needs access to that currently requires admin, and adjust permissions to that thing.

Comment: Problem with the app is I have 0 clue why it fails. Sometimes it'll work fine but if it doesn't, running as admin always fixes it. I DO NOT want to make someone an admin.

Comment: What is the name of the program or what does it do?

Comment: Its SIP Soft Phone, it lets my employees use the computer as a phone. I'm not the one that set it up, I'm just the person that manages it now.